# How can I use 'window.location.href' in a jQuery HTML insertion or wrap?

Tags: jquery, insert, replace, uri, word-wrap

I'm trying to insert a link into an empty < a > that has the id "popup". The link will open the current page in a popup box (with parameters I'll define later). I'm trying to string together the HTML needed to make a hyperlink plus the JS variable 'window.location.href' -- how can these be strung together? i.e. how do I fix this to make it work, or rewrite it as a function with 'window.location.href' as a variable:

```
$("#popup").html('<a href=' . window.location.href . '>open popup</a>');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("#popup").html($('<a />', { href: window.location.href, text: 'open popup' }));
```

Or for the popup:

```
$("#popup").html($('<a />', { 
  href: window.location.href, 
  text: 'open popup',
  target: '_blank'
}));
```

Or, using [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) for parameters:

```
$("#popup").html($('<a />', { 
  href: '#', 
  click: function() { window.open(window.location.href, 'popup', 'params'); }
}));
```

---

There were 2 problems with your original approach:

```
$("#popup").html('<a href=' . window.location.href . '>open popup</a>');
```

1. Use `+` to concatenate strings
2. You need quotes around the attribute

Like this:

```
$("#popup").html('<a href="' + window.location.href + '">open popup</a>');
```

Comment: And 3. You'd need to `&`-encode any HTML-special characters inside the URL. +1 for the version without the HTML string slinging!

Answer (score 1):

btw: in javascript you combine strings with a `+` instead of `.` (PHP, right?):

```
var something = 'Hello' + ' ' + 'World'; // => 'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#popup").attr("href",window.location.href).attr("target","_blank").text("Open Popup");
```

Comment: `#popup` seems to be a container, not an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the link, so the href is the same.

```
$("#popup").attr('href',window.location.href);
```

e.g.

```
<a id="popup" href="">popup</a>
```

becomes

```
<a id="popup" href="yourcurrenturl">popup</a>
```

EDIT:

To give you a little inspiration for other techniques for popups (forgive me if this if this code doesn't work, I just whipped to together quickly)

HTML

```
 <a href="http://www.developertipoftheday.com" rel="popup" target="alexsite">open alex site in popup</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$("a[rel = 'popup']").click(function (event) {

    var popupWindow= window.open($(this).attr("href"), $(this).attr("target"), "status=true,toolbar=false,menubar=false,location=false,width=1018,height=792")

    if (popupWindow=== null) {

        alert("A messasge to inform the user, that the popup has been blocked");
    }

});
```

Comment: Glad you like it, hopefully it answers you question directly. However i'd recommend doing some more research - as you may find a different approach to popups more reusable. Take a look at the source code for this popup plugin http://www.webhipster.com/plugins/popify/ for some inspiration.